# Identify 3rd Friday in a sequence of Dates

Tags: r, date, data.table, lubridate

The code below has a list of dates and if the the date is the last day in he month, for all the dates in dataset (not on the calendar), then it flags the date as the last day in the month.

```
data = data.frame(day  = seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"),as.Date("2016-05-10"),"day"), weekday = weekdays ( seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"),as.Date("2016-05-10"),"day")))
excludeDays <- c("Saturday", "Sunday")
data <- subset(data, !weekdays(data$day) %in% excludeDays) #exclude weekend
setDT(data)
data[, LastDayInMonth := day == max(day), by = list(year(day),month(day)  )]
head(data,100)
```

I also need to add a column that flags (TRUE/FALSE) any Friday in the data that is the 3rd Friday in the month. Any idea on that?

for example 2014-01-17, 2014-02-21,......2014-05-16 etc... are 3rd fridays.

Thank you.

Comment: you can directly create a data.table with `data.table()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cover the corner case when the data starts in the middle of the month you can try this:

```
occ <- 3L   # 3rd occurrence of selected weekday
data[, ThirdFridayInMonth := weekday == "Friday" &
       as.integer(day - lubridate::floor_date(day, "month")) %/% 7L + 1L == occ]
```

This works also for other weekdays in the month, e.g., to flag every first Monday.

**Edit:** Explanation as requested.

The basic idea is that the 1st Friday in each month must be one of the first 7 days of each month, the 2nd Friday must be one of the days 8 to 14 and so forth. So, `lubridate::floor_date(day, "month")` computes the first day of the month `day` is located in. Now, you build the difference which is a `difftime` object which needs to be converted into an `integer`. If `day` happens to be the first of a month this is `0`. Now you use integer division `%/%` which returns 0 for the first 7 days of the month, 1 for the second 7 days, etc. which is then adjusted by adding 1.

**Edit 2:** Improved code

While writing the explanation, I recognized that the code can be further improved.

We can use the day of month directly which saves us from computing the difference in dates and subsequent conversion to integer:

```
data[, ThirdFridayInMonth := weekday == "Friday" &
       (mday(day) - 1) %/% 7L + 1L == occ]
```

Here, I use `mday` (part of `data.table` package) instead of `as.integer(format(day, "%d"))`.

Comment: can you explain what  as.integer(day - lubridate::floor_date(day, "month")) %/% 7L + 1L == occ]  is doing?

Comment: @user3022875 Thank you for asking. I've added an explanation and improved code to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
data[, numWeek := 1:.N, by = .(year(day), month(day), weekday)]

data[numWeek == 3 & weekday == "Friday"]
```

Or to add as a column:

```
data[, is3rdFriday := numWeek == 3 & weekday == "Friday"]
```

If you're looking for 3rd Friday in the calendar, as opposed to the 3rd Friday in your data, then you can do it even simpler:

```
data[, is3rdFriday := (mday(day) - 1) %/% 7 + 1 == 3 & weekday == "Friday"]
```

Comment: this works but there is a corner case when the data starts in the second week. then the 3rd friday is counted as the second and doesn't get flagged

Comment: To cover the corner case you can do `data[, ThirdFridayInMonth := weekday == "Friday" &
       as.integer(day - lubridate::floor_date(day, "month")) %/% 7L + 1L == 3L]`

Comment: @user3022875 wasn't clear from OP that's what you wanted - added

Answer (score 2):

Try this - without data.table:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame(day  = seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"),
                              as.Date("2016-05-10"),"day"),
                  weekday = weekdays(seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"),
                                         as.Date("2016-05-10"),"day")))
data$year_month <- floor_date(data$day, unit = 'month')
fri3 <- filter(data, weekday == 'Friday') %>%
  group_by(year_month) %>% slice(3)

data$Third_Fri <- data$day %in% fri3$day
```

You can remove year_month later

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it:

```
data[, is3Friday:=cumsum(weekday=="Friday"), by=substring(day, 1, 7)]
data[, is3Friday:=ifelse(weekday=="Friday" & is3Friday==3, TRUE, FALSE)]

data[is3Friday==TRUE]
           day weekday LastDayInMonth is3Friday
 1: 2014-01-17  Friday          FALSE      TRUE
 2: 2014-02-21  Friday          FALSE      TRUE
 3: 2014-03-21  Friday          FALSE      TRUE
 4: 2014-04-18  Friday          FALSE      TRUE
 5: 2014-05-16  Friday          FALSE      TRUE
 6: 2014-06-20  Friday          FALSE      TRUE
```